# Can't figure out how to fix non-manifold geometry in my game title

Tags: mesh, geometry

[image]

So I have this mesh and I'm having issues figuring out why these are non-manifold geometries, I've pulled them apart, dissolved them, merged them by distances, checked for any faces that shouldn't be there or extra vertices / edges and I don't understand why these are being marked non-manifold, normally this wouldn't even be a problem because I won't be further modifying the mesh further, but I need to UV unwrap this to apply a texture to it in my game and that requires manifold geometry from what I understand, I also can't dissolve these edges to make the title look sleek and clean.

I've tried quite a few guides on non-manifold geometry and it seems like my entire model is derped both in terms of vertices and edges, faces are okay apparently but I don't understand what I did wrong, I just extruded and merged vertices by edges to make essentially all of it, and even if I had extruded extra edges and forgot to undo them I merged all the selected points manually and by selection by trait and neither produces any result so I don't imagine there are duplicate vertices / edges.

Any help for fixing and/or improving my modeling technique would be greatly appreciated, I've made a few models but this is the first time I've ever even encountered this sort of problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqUoXQXGYPrqvPpo2CdKPBRoVGIl1vWA/view?usp=sharing

A link to the blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure you merged by distance? I tried it upon first opening your file and it removed 195 vertices right from the get go (shown at bottom).

[image: Verts]

As you can see from the face orientation overlay, half of your mesh has faces facing inwards and the other half outwards. There is also a problem with the circled face (there may be a couple more instances). It looks connected, but it is in fact overlapping (you can tell by the z-fighting). This may be a result of the merge, but it needs attention nonetheless.

[image: Faces]

You can fix the normal direction by selecting all and then selecting `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`, but the face will have to be edited and "re-connected" manually.

[image: Normal]

Comment: Thank you so much, not only did you make me understand why I was failing to fix my problem but you also fixed another problem for me I didn't even know I had (which I thought I checked for using the face orientation but I didn't.)

My error was Selecting by trait - non-manifold and than attempting to merge by distance (which is what the guides I read told me to do.) but selecting the entire mesh by vertices and than merging by distance worked exactly as you showed and fixed 99% of the issue, the rest of the non-manifold geometry was also fixed by some editing then your second suggestion TYVM

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad it works for you.